# Kendo MVC multiple uploaders

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

I'm using the kendo controls with MVC. I have a basic uploader working, but I need to create them dynamically and handle that code on the back end. Here's my simple example that's working

```
<input name="attachments" type="file" id="attachments" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#attachments").kendoUpload({
            async: {
                saveUrl: '@Url.Action("Save", "AppConfig")',
                autoUpload: true
            }
        });
});
</script>
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> attachments)
    {

        if (SaveUploadedFile(attachments, "Background"))
        {
            return Content("");
        }
        else
        {
            return Content("error");
        }

    }
```

However, what I need to do is create the ids dynamically and handle it on the backend. So this is how I'm making the file uploaders

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    string fid = String.Format("{0}{1}", @item.fieldType, @item.appConfigId.ToString());
                <input name="@fid" id="@fid" type="file" />
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        $("#@fid").kendoUpload({
                        async: {
                            saveUrl: '@Url.Action("Save", "AppConfig")',
                            autoUpload: true
                        }
                    });
                });
                </script>

}
```

Now I get that the HttpPostedFileBase argument has to match your id of your html element, but I have no idea how to modify the code behind, so that I can take in multiple uploaders. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use the **[multiple](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/upload#configuration-multiple)** functionality of the Uploader? It is enabled by default.

Comment: Because my current situation will not allow that. Each file upload pertains to someting specific. I just dumbed down what my code is doing for the use of people reading it here. The for loop this sits in is much more complicated.